# I am failing to commit to mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial

I tried committing to a local hg repo and it refuses:

```
trouble committing plot.py!
note: commit message saved in .hg/last-message.txt
abort: Permission denied: /home/md/md_perf/.hg/store/data/plot.py.i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file permissions are messed up inside the local repository -- probably someone else pushed or committed to that repository without making sure they were leaving the permissions in a state usable by your whole group.  Try these, with the appropriate substitutions, and sudo if necessary:

```
chgrp -R yourgroup /home/md/md_perf
chmod -R g+rwX /home/md/md_perf
find /home/md/md_perf -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

Comment: I think I committed into it with a different user, so the file was owned by the wrong guy.

Answer (score 0):

So i Got the kind of same issues my issues was when i try to commit i am getting error that user name is not setup so when i try to add it this way `sudo hg config --edit` i get this error the permission error and i have tried the above method and wasn't able to fix the issues then at the end i had no choice other than adding the user manually
**

> Steps To do

`code .hg/hgrc`  you can use any ide here i am using vscode

> Then Add user like this and please make sure it's the same as your repository in remote so mine was thalinda.bandara so i have added that and email too

`[ui] username = Your Name <your.email@example.com>` 
and yes your email should be in `<email>`

**